# Split Random Data Training And Data Testing in Pandas CSV

Tags: python, pandas

I'm newbie using Python

First of all, I would like to split my data training and data testing where

> Data Training = 6 and Data Testing = 2

I confused using csv file to random data training and data testing

I've been trying to split data training and data testing but sequence same with csv file

Here we go my data training and data testing:

```
def ambilData():
df = pd.read_csv("datalatihnodummy.csv", sep=';')
dropdata = df.drop(['data', 'Klasifikasi'], axis =1)
datalatih = dropdata.iloc[:6]
datauji = dropdata.iloc[6:]
return datalatih, datauji
```

and here is a output of training :

> > [image]

and here is a output of testing:

> [image]

I would like to test Hepatitis B only or Hepatitis A only. 
Anyone know how to random my dataset? thx u^

here is my data: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1tD3h0aS-AB4qrMg2vw0fHcMx6F3jzJCx

Comment: I think it is much easier to do it with `scikit learn`. You can directly do it on a dataframe. Google it.

Comment: i kno men using sciket more easier, but its for myhomework and not allowed to use any kind of libraries. thx men^^

Comment: Not sure what you mean since pandas is a library

Comment: except scikit i mean hehehe, anyway thx menn^^

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x_data, y_data, test_size=0.15, random_state=1)
```

it will randomly split your data into training and testing data.

the **x_data** is the independent variable - so here you want to drop the 'Klasifikasi'

the **y_data** is the dependent variable in yours df it's the 'Klasifikasi'

hope it will help

Comment: hopefully work, but im not allowed using a sklearn. Anyway, thx u^

Comment: so, try to use the frac param: select 50 % rows from df1 `df2 =
df1.sample(frac =.50) `